# Disable inverted checkbox color in VS Code markdown file

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

In the editor VS Code markdown checkboxes are inverted in color.
This is not a selection, this is permanent inversion.
How can I disable this inversion?

Example: [Inversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GauW.png)

I tried to turn on and off extensions, but that did not help.

I expect:

## My file

- [ ] item_1
- [x] item_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the ToDo tree extension
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.todo-tree

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).